# Bad sql performance with a simple where condition on an indexed column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a very simple sql where statement

```
  SELECT    `genre_application`.`genre_id`
      FROM  `genre_application`
      WHERE `genre_application`.`application_id` = 310633997
```

which takes around 2 seconds even with indexes on the column.

```
{
"query_block": {
"select_id": 1,
"cost_info": {
  "query_cost": "2098202.80"
},
"table": {
  "table_name": "genre_application",
  "access_type": "index",
  "key": "PRIMARY",
  "used_key_parts": [
    "genre_id",
    "application_id"
  ],
  "key_length": "8",
  "rows_examined_per_scan": 10363019,
  "rows_produced_per_join": 1036301,
  "filtered": "10.00",
  "using_index": true,
  "cost_info": {
    "read_cost": "1890942.42",
    "eval_cost": "207260.38",
    "prefix_cost": "2098202.80",
    "data_read_per_join": "23M"
  },
  "used_columns": [
    "genre_id",
    "application_id"
  ],
  "attached_condition": "(`genre_application`.`application_id` = 310633997)"
}
}
```

How could I improve the execution time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT ga.`genre_id`
FROM `genre_application` ga
WHERE ga.`application_id` = 310633997
```

You need an index where `application_id` is the first key in the index.  The best index is a composite index on `genre_application(application_id, genre_id)`.  Note that the order of the keys in the index matters.

Comment: Wow, that was a quick reply. Works perfect 00:20:00 
SELECT `genre_application`.`genre_id` FROM `genre_application` WHERE `genre_application`.`application_id` = 310633997 LIMIT 0, 300 2 row(s) returned 0.00036 sec / 0.0000079 sec

Comment: Smells like the Query Cache kicked in.  Still, I agree that that is the optimal index.